# Pesaran cross-sectional dependence test in panel data

Tags: stata, panel-data

I was testing the cross sectional independence test using `Pesaran CD` test in Stata 10 for the panel data using the `N=50 and T=18`. After running the fixed effect with time dummies (effects), I got a negative value for the test with the `p` value >1 (which is not possible). I checked the paper on this: http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0113, but they didn't talk about the negative value at all. I would really appreciate if you can help me to interpret the results.

```
xtreg Y  X1 X2 i.year,fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs      =       900
Group variable: state                           Number of groups   =        50

R-sq:  within  = 0.4336                         Obs per group: min =        18
       between = 0.0417                                        avg =        18
       overall = 0.3772                                        max =        18

                                                F(19,825)          =     33.24
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.0215                        Prob > F           =    0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           X1 |  -.0008466   .0005767    -1.47   0.142    -.0019787    .0002854
           X2 |    .185078   .0304043     6.09   0.000     .1253991     .244757
             |
        year |
       1993  |  -.0101846   .0029659    -3.43   0.001    -.0160061   -.0043631
       1994  |  -.0173621   .0028749    -6.04   0.000     -.023005   -.0117192
       1995  |  -.0046886   .0029062    -1.61   0.107     -.010393    .0010159
       1996  |  -.0175546   .0028879    -6.08   0.000     -.023223   -.0118862
       1997  |   -.009572    .002962    -3.23   0.001     -.015386    -.003758
       1998  |   -.012109   .0029123    -4.16   0.000    -.0178254   -.0063926
       1999  |  -.0097348   .0029043    -3.35   0.001    -.0154356   -.0040341
       2000  |  -.0137918   .0028784    -4.79   0.000    -.0194416   -.0081419
       2001  |    .004144   .0029323     1.41   0.158    -.0016116    .0098996
       2002  |   .0188509   .0028925     6.52   0.000     .0131733    .0245285
       2003  |   .0058601   .0028772     2.04   0.042     .0002127    .0115076
       2004  |  -.0005801   .0028731    -0.20   0.840    -.0062195    .0050594
       2005  |  -.0085907   .0029534    -2.91   0.004    -.0143877   -.0027937
       2006  |   -.018118   .0028702    -6.31   0.000    -.0237516   -.0124843
       2007  |  -.0164648   .0028771    -5.72   0.000    -.0221121   -.0108174
       2008  |  -.0352191   .0028805   -12.23   0.000    -.0408731   -.0295652
       2009  |   .0094679   .0032904     2.88   0.004     .0030094    .0159265
             |
       _cons |   .0467515   .0024088    19.41   0.000     .0420234    .0514797
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .00686051
     sigma_e |  .01433916
         rho |   .1862708   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0:     F(49, 825) =     4.02             Prob > F = 0.0000


xtcsd, pesaran abs
 Pesaran's test of cross sectional independence =    -2.673, Pr = 1.9925
  Average absolute value of the off-diagonal elements =     0.215
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant lines in the code file `xtcsd.ado`, to view which type

```
viewsource xtcsd.ado
```

are `163`-`165`, which read

```
    di in gr "Pesaran's test of cross sectional independence = "/*
    */in ye %9.3f `pesaran' in gr ", Pr = " %6.4f /*
    */ in ye 2*(1-norm(abs(`pesaran')))
```

The last line of code is the one that produces the p-value, and it behaves as expected under version control, with the value of the statistic that you get

```
. version 9: di 2*(1-norm(abs(-2.673)))
.00751763
```

So, there is no ostensible reason why your computed statistic should result in an abnormal p-value. I suggest you `set trace on` and check what is going on, or show us the output.

By the way, you should check what version of the `xtcsd` package you have. You can check using

```
. which xtcsd
*! version 1.1.1        R.E. De Hoyos and V. Sarafidis 16may2006
```

Comment: Thanks nu for the insight. I checked the version and it is version 1.1.0 (how do I have the new version?; stata says it is the latest). As to the code in the line 165, I figure out (by googling) that stata 11 doesn't have norm (http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-08/msg00761.html). Is it possible for us to change that content?

Comment: In order to get the latest version of the `xtcsd` package, type `ssc install xtcsd, replace` at the prompt. Also, since `xtcsd` runs under version control (version 6), `norm` should be okay. However, if you do run into trouble relating to the use of the `norm` function, then starting Stata 10.1, there was a reorganization of the density functions, and the `norm` function was replaced by the `normal` function. See `help density_functions##normal`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. The problem occurred because of using the old version. Now, I got the correct answer Pr = 0.0075.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to vote for the answer; i don't have enough reputation. Is there alternative way to do that?

Comment: You don't need to vote -- you can simply accept it by clicking the check mark underneath the downvote button. See the end of the "How do I ask questions here?" section [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).